# Angularjs pass variable to ejs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ejs

I'm trying to pass a Angular variable to EJS so I can select an object property based on a previous input. In this case {{ baz }} should print '2'. I want to do something like:

index.ejs

```
<%= foo[{{baz}}].bar %>
```

And have the following result :

```
<%= foo[2].bar %>
```